# Assign same sequence number to a group of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with one-to-many rows and I want to track changes for it.
I'm trying to write a query to get the same sequence number to a group of rows which have same ID number, and if any change happens for the corresponding ID number then I want to repeat the set of rows so that I keep track of these changes with a new and I can track this in a fact.

Here an example, starting with data:

```
person_id_number  person_type  start_date end_date
0001              kid          2003       2009
0001              student      2010       2014
0002              teacher      2010       9999
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
Person_id_number person_type  p_key
0001             kid          1          
0001             student      1
0002             teacher      3
```

Now, there is a new row for the same person_id:

```
person_id_number  person_type  start_date end_date
0001              kid          2003       2009
0001              student      2010       2014
0001              teacher      2015       9999
0002              teacher      2010       9999
```

The output should now be:

```
Person_id_number person_type  p_key
0001             kid          1          
0001             student      1
0001             kid          2          
0001             student      2
0001             teacher      2
0002             teacher      3
```

How can I do that in a SQL query?

Comment: How do you know when the new row was added? Or if not exactly when, then how do you know it wasn't added at the same time as `kid` and `student`, and that those two rows were inserted together? Does that p_key exist anywhere or are you trying to generate it on the fly as part of your query?

Comment: The data that i'm getting is from an application(OLTP) system which always has a current snapshot of data that they have in the system. Consider that we process this data daily. Today we got 2 rows and tomorrow I got an extra record for the same id_number, this indicates that a new row has been added into that system for that Id_number. I'm trying to generate sequence as part of the query on the fly

Comment: Should there be an individual row for kid with p_key 1 and the two rows you are showing with p_key = 1 should be p_key=2?

Comment: So as an insert into a table that has a p_key column? Once you've compared the snapshot with the current data and seen there is a new row (or any change?) you want to insert that all that data from the snapshot with an incremented p_key?

Comment: Let me share a sample data set. In that way it becomes more clear.

Comment: Do you have an ADD_DTTM Field on the table for when the row was inserted?

Comment: Yes. There is a date_added field on that table

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/sampledata

Comment: you can add a field in the select list that is a query to count the number of kid rows with a date_added <= current row for the same person id number. i would add this as an answer but i can't get it to submit

Comment: I did not understand your explanation. I have shared a spreadsheet of how the data should look like since i have difficulty formatting it as a comment.

Comment: @AlexPoole: i have actually edited my data set. Could you please take a look now.

Comment: SO is being stupid an won't let me post my answer in the comment or answer. Sorry, i'm sure @AlexPoole can help

Comment: could you please share the solution in a spreadsheet so that i can take a look @wyatt shipman

Comment: @WyattShipman What error are you seeing when you try to post it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos red box  that says "An error occured submitting the answer."

Comment: @WyattShipman No specific message is really a problem. Try to open a new browser log on on your account and try again. Something like a incognito window in chrome browser

Comment: @JorgeCampos didn't work in Chrome incognito... Same error showed

Comment: @JorgeCampos it won't let me post the SQL portion of my answer. it is formatted as code. not sure why SO doesn't like it.

Comment: @WyattShipman Add your answer in a pastebin link so we can see what is your answer please

Answer (score -1):

You can use the date_added to aggregate how many distinct date_added values are on the table less than or equal to the current row. The query in the select statement should be what you are looking for for the p_key field.

```
select c.* , 
    (select COUNT(distinct date_added) 
     from table ci 
     where ci.person_id_number=c.person_id_number 
     and ci.date_added <= c.date_added) p_key
from table c
```